# Merging RestAPI with a chatbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest, flask

I am a beginner to RestAPI and I am in a situation where I should merge a chatbot that I built into this RestAPI.
The chatbot was done using python and there is a function chat(), when calling this function the program enters into an infinite loop chatting with the chatbot until I write "quit" the program terminates.

The RestAPI program is here

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import chatting
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class chatbot(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return{"data": chatting.chat()}
    def post(self):
        return{"data": "posted"}

api.add_resource(chatbot, '/hello')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug= True)
```

I imported chatting which is the script that has the chatting function to chat with the chatbot
This program does not work properly.

This is the API testing program:

```
import requests

Base = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
response = requests.get(Base + "/hello")
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when calling this function the program enters into an infinite loop

i can't say for sure without seeing your code, but this here is a problem my friend.
rest api requests should not live for that long.
you should change your program logic.
each rest call should just send a text and get a response.
your infinite while loop is actually now your api server, it runs for ever and waits for requests.

your chat function should look like this:

```
def chat(text):
  response = do_your_thing(text)
  return response
```

Comment: Yes but what about the chat() does not take any arguments?

Comment: if your bot can answer without any input then you can omit it, otherwise you have to change your python code.

Answer (score 0):

A post function can be used to send an audio and return an audio file